# How do I get a random key assigned by Firebase Realtime Database for Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever I try to get the key, it gives me a random key and not the correct one that I had before in the log, and the data is also not deleted.

```
FirebaseDatabase databas = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myjsd = database.getReference().child("JoinUS_Data");
```

Here is the data I am trying to delete:

[image: An image of my database]

This is how I am currently trying to remove it:

```
String key = myjsd.push().getKey();
myjsd.child(key).removeValue();
Log.d("keylog", "onComplete: "+key);
```

After running that code, the data in the database does not get deleted and I keep getting a random key in the logs:

```
2022-02-04 11:49:57.102 10212-10212/com.example.pahalbackend D/keylog: onComplete: -Mv2NvEgCBoWN3b6q5nQ
```

Comment: Please write your question more properly. As you wrote your question it does not help us to understand what your real problem is. Whether you want new key or get specific key from database.

Answer (score 1):

The [`DatabaseReference#push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()) in the following line creates a new `DatabaseReference` object, with a randomly generated key based on the current time. This is why the data isn't being deleted as you expect, because you are "deleting" data that doesn't even exist yet.

```
String key = myjsd.push().getKey();
```

To correct this, you need to find a key that exists in your database. To do this, you must first [perform a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) for it using one of the many [available filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data). In the below example, I'm searching out data that contains a `"name"` field equal to `"jehe"`.

```
Query myjsdQuery = myjsd // the parent Reference
    .orderByChild("name") // the property to search on
    .equalTo("jehe") // return children that have "name"="jehe"
    .limitToFirst(1); // return at most one result

myjsdQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            child.removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference ref) {
                    if (error !== null) {
                        // Failed. TODO: Log/handle exception.
                        Log.w(TAG, "myjsdQuery:onDeleted", databaseError.toException());
                        return;
                    }

                    Log.i(TAG, "myjsdQuery:onDeleted", "Successfully deleted data!");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Failed. TODO: Log/handle exception.
        Log.w(TAG, "myjsdQuery:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can simplify the above code using [`Task`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html) chaining which is similar to a `Promise` in `JavaScript`:

```
Query myjsdQuery = myjsd // the parent Reference
    .orderByChild("name") // the property to search on
    .equalTo("jehe") // return children that have "name"="jehe"
    .limitToFirst(1); // return at most one result

myjsdQuery.get()
    .onSuccessTask(new SuccessContinuation<DataSnapshot, String>() {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Task<void> then(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // this is set to work when there is only one child of the returned data!
            // you'll need to use Tasks.WhenAll() or a multi-location database update for more than one result
            for (DataSnapshot child : parent.getChildren()) {
                return child.removeValue();
            }
            return Tasks.forResult(null); // handle case where there are no results
        }
    })
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<void>() {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<void> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Failed. TODO: Log/handle exception.
                Log.w(TAG, "myjsdQuery:onCompleteError", databaseError.toException());
                return;
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "myjsdQuery:onDeleted", "Successfully deleted data!");
        }
    });
```

**Disclaimer**: My Java is a little rusty and this was written free-hand, so expect a typo or two.